# How to make Monaco Editor not to close suggest widget when first key pressed is space

Tags: monaco-editor

My `CompletionItemProvider` has these `triggerCharacters`:

```
public triggerCharacters = ["+", "-", "$", "*", "/"];
```

e.g. when editing expression in it, and press `+` i get:

[image: Suggest triggered by plus operator]

Now when I press `space` (people like to do after operator) the suggest widget is canceled (closed). **I need to keep it opened.** To add `" "` to `triggerCharacters` is not a solution.

Looking into vscode sources, the problematic part is in [suggestModel.ts/_onNewContext()](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/editor/contrib/suggest/suggestModel.ts) function:

```
            if (!this._context.auto) {
                // freeze when IntelliSense was manually requested
                this._completionModel.lineContext = oldLineContext;
                isFrozen = this._completionModel.items.length > 0;

                if (isFrozen && ctx.leadingWord.word.length === 0) {
                    // there were results before but now there aren't
                    // and also we are not on a word anymore -> cancel
                    this.cancel();
                    return;
                }
            }
```

I haven't find a place where to hook to this code to change behaviour.

I was thinking to register `editor.onDidChangeModelContent()` or `editor.onKeyDown()` and if the last edit was `" "` and the suggest widget has been opened (or recently opened), trigger `"editor.action.triggerSuggest"` action.

But I am not able to find legal way how to find out if suggest widget is opened. Plus even if I was able to, I have doubts if it wold work.

Comment: Try `editor.getContribution('editor.contrib.suggestController').model.state` where `editor` is your monaco editor instance. A value of `0` means the suggest widget is closed. I assume `1` means open.